# Element is transforming before hover (translateZ)

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to add a new hover effect to my menu, I'm mocking it up in HTML/CSS here:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dWOBNG

HTML

```
<ul>
 <li class="cube" >
  <a href="#">
   <span class="flippety">
    flip
   </span>
   <span class="flop">
    flop
   </span>
  </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
   /* Set-up */
body {
color: rgb(6, 106, 117);
text-transform: uppercase;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 100%;
background: #e3e3e3;
padding: 3em 0 0 0;
line-height: 60px;
-webkit-perspective: 1000px; /* <-NB */
}

/* Container box to set the sides relative to */
.cube {
width: 30%;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 60px;
display: block;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .75s;
transition: transform .75s; /* Animate the transform properties */
background-color: red;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform-style: preserve-3d; /* <-NB */
}

/* The two faces of the cube */
.flippety,.flop {
border: 1px solid rgba(147, 184, 189, .8);
display: block;
}

/* Position the faces */
.flippety {
-webkit-transform: translateZ(30px);
transform: translateZ(30px);
background-color: green;
}

.flop {
-webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg)   translateZ(-30px);
transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-30px);
background-color: yellow;
}

/* Rotate the cube */
.cube:hover {
-webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
transform: rotateX(90deg); /* Text bleed at 90º */
}
```

The issue is that it's transforming before I actually hover over the element itself as you can see here:
[.gif of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPGtJ.gif)

I'm struggling to work out why exactly...

I think it may be something to do with the 2 span tags wanting to "stack" on top of each other but I can't see another way round this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I changed the cube class to the  tag.

My bad, this solved it perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  color: rgb(6, 106, 117);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  background: #e3e3e3;
  padding: 3em 0 0 0;
  line-height: 60px;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
}
.cube {
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 60px;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .75s;
  transition: transform .75s;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d; /* <-NB */
}
.cube a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 60px;
}

.flippety,.flop {
  display: block;
  color: #FFF;
}
.flippety {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(30px);
  transform: translateZ(30px);
  background-color: green;
}
.flop {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg)   translateZ(-30px);
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-30px);
  background-color: yellow;
  color: #000;
}
.cube:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li class="cube" >
  <a href="#">
   <span class="flippety">
    flip
   </span>
   <span class="flop">
    flop
   </span>
  </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```